# How to/Best practice to add multiple (over 100) custom annotations into mapView Swift?

Tags: swift, annotations, mkmapview, mapkit

I am making custom annotations on specific coordinates to have all "name", "description" and "image" in the callout box but I have very many areas to annotate (over 100) and I have been doing them one at a time. What are your suggestions to do this? JSON? Something else?

Comment: If you want to add a lot of annotations, just use `addAnnotations`, to which you can supply an array of annotations. Re JSON, that's really more of a format to exchange information with a web service, so it's not really applicable here (though if you're submitting 100 different requests to your web service, redesigning it to process multiple ones in one request might make sense, but that's not related to the multiple annotations question).

Comment: The more interesting question is how to show that many annotations on a map (as they start to overlap, yielding a substandard UX) and WWDC 2011 [Visualizing Information Geographically with MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/111/) shows you how you might start to tackle that problem, by clustering the annotations (about 23 minutes into the video).

Comment: But this question is too broad and is a bit unclear. You might want to narrow down your question, showing us what you tried, describe what behavior you experienced, and describe how that differed from what you expected or hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing all of the annotations in an array and then call

```
func addAnnotations(_ annotations: [MKAnnotation])
```

with your array of annotations.

See https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview/1451889-addannotations for more details.